# Could I send JSON data with LoRa and how?

Tags: arduino, gps, sodaq-mbili, lora, lorawan

I've a SODAQ Mbili board with a LoRa bee. I've also a GPS sensor. Below you could find how I add the bee and the sensor.

[image]

On that board I make a JSON string with the GPS coordinates and I'll send that data over the LoRa network. But How could I do that.

In the source code I've download they use next code:

```
LoRaModemMicrochip modem(&MODEM_SERIAL, &debugSerial);
Device libTest(&modem, &debugSerial);

void readGPSData() {
    GPSSensor gpsSens(4.3, 51.222, 15.5, 0);
    dumpSendResult(gpsSens);
}

void dumpSendResult(Sensor& sns) {
    bool sendResult = libTest.send(sns, true);
}
```

I'll change this code like code below so I could send my JSON data

```
LoRaModemMicrochip modem(&MODEM_SERIAL, &debugSerial);
Device libTest(&modem, &debugSerial);

void readGPSData() {
    String json = "My JSON code";
    dumpJsonResult(json);
}

void dumpJsonResult(String& text) {
    bool sendResult = libTest.send(text, true);
}
```

But it gives me this error:

> ***In function `void dumpJsonResult(String&)`:***
>
> **Error:** no matching function for call to `Device::send(String&, bool)`
>
> ```
> bool sendResult = libTest.send(text, true);
>                                          ^
> ```

Did you know how I could send JSON data to the LoRaWAN?

Comment: sending json over lorawan is a very bad practices due to huge data overhead. You should consider compress your data as much as possible by only sending really required bytes. Otherwise, you will kill your duty cycle time !

Comment: LoRa or LoRaWAN? Not the same thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have correct NWSessionKey and APPSessionKey and so on, you could try to onboard your device over Actility's free partner zone.
https://partners.thingpark.com/

Once you do that, you would need to:

- Learn how to perform a *downlink*
- Create your own *payload mechanism*, such as coding your GPS over signed ints for Lat, long and Alt.
- Then decode it within your device

Your device could also send ack to an Applicative Server you would plug to Actility's solution (REST-POST/JSON)

Let us know how it goes
Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

What are the libraries used? I haven't found LoRaModemMicrochip object definition on sodaq site.

Have you looked at http://support.sodaq.com/sodaq-one/lorabee/?

I would strongly suggest you not to use JSON with LoRa, as this is very verbose and will use a lot of air time, while the bands where LoRa run have strong duty cycle constrains.